# Cursor returns null when getting filepath from URI

Tags: android, uri, gallery, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
```

**cursor.getString(columnIndex) *Returns Null*** 
Where as the **selectedImage** is not null.

Any suggestion on how I can create file from URI?

Comment: May be you are picking up a google photos image..the image is not in your phone but on google photos

Answer (score 0):

> Cursor returns null when getting filepath from URI

A `Uri` is not a file. A `Uri` does not have to point to a file, let alone a file on the filesystem that you can access.

> Any suggestion on how I can create file from URI?

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified the `Uri`. Ideally, just use that `InputStream` directly. If, for some reason, you truly need a file:

- Create a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`)
- Copy the bytes from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`
- Use the file that you just created, deleting it when you are done

Answer (score -3):

Use this method to get path:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    // just some safety built in
    if (uri == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // try to retrieve the image from the media store first
    // this will only work for images selected from gallery
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    // this is our fallback here
    return uri.getPath();
}
```

And in onACtivityResult use this:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
```

Comment: How this would help? This code is almost the same as his ... Obviously not all ContentProvider's uris have path

Comment: Moreover, `managedQuery()` has been deprecated for over six years.